# Distribution of X-U(0,1) conditioned on sigma algebra of Y/X, where is Y is U(0,1)?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation, sigma-algebra

The question I have is:

Define X,Y to be two independent uniform(0,1) random variables and $Z:=\frac{Y}{X}$

Compute
$P(X<x|\sigma(Z))$

The answer given apparently by "straightforward elementary computations" is for $x\geq 0$

$P(X<x|\sigma(Z))$=min$\{{x^2,1}\}\mathbb{I}_{Z\leq 1}$ $+$ min$\{{x^2 Z^2,1}\}\mathbb{I}_{Z\geq 1}$.

My idea was to condition on the $Z\leq 1$ and ${Z\geq 1}$  then compute using the joint density of X and Y, but this seems to work for the first term but doesn't for the second? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a question from a textbook/assignment/exam? If so, please consider adding `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @whuber Is this actually a duplicate of the indicated post? That deals with the distribution of $Z$, but this doesn't seem to be asking for that. If the indicated thread does completely cover the answer to this, I think at least a brief comment here explaining why those very differently phrased questions are the same would be helpful.

Comment: @Glen I interpreted this question as requesting the "straightforward elementary computations" needed to obtain the distribution of a ratio of independent uniform variables, and then saw those computations explicitly laid out in clear answers in the duplicate.  I did not see any request, explicit or implicit, to re-interpret the more formal language of sigma algebras.  If, on the other hand, the duplicate had been closed with a reference to *this* question, then I agree that might have required an explanation.

Comment: @whuber this isn't a duplicate of that question, I'm not trying to work out the ratio distribution, I'm conditioning on the sigma algebra and then trying to obtain the above probability.

Comment: Thank you Dan.  After rereading your question carefully (prompted by @Glen_b) I recognized that difference and reopened it last night.